# Add customer email to order via observer make export csv error

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Here is my observer to add the code to show email in order grid

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block->getId() == 'sales_order_grid') {

        $block->addColumnAfter(
            'email',
            array(
                'header'   => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email'),
                'align'    => 'left',
                'index'    => 'email',
                'filter_index'    => 'email',
            ),
            'shipping_name'
        );

        // Set the new columns order.. otherwise our column would be the last one
        $block->sortColumnsByOrder();
    }
}

public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $select = $collection->getSelect();

    $select->joinLeft(array('oa' => 'customer_entity'),'oa.entity_id = main_table.customer_id', array('email'));

}
```

but it makes the CSV export function error, here is the error

You cannot define a correlation name 'oa' more than once

```
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\Varien\Db\Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'oa.entity_id = ...', Array, NULL)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\Zend\Db\Select.php(357): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'oa.entity_id = ...', Array, NULL)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\local\Test\Admin\Model\Observer.php(67): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'oa.entity_id = ...', Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Test_Admin_Model_Observer->salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Test_Admin_Model_Observer), 'salesOrderGridC...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php(590): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(565): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_beforeLoad()
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(951): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(1008): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_exportIterateCollection('_exportCsvItem', Array)
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php(703): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->getCsvFile()
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->exportCsvAction()
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('exportCsv')
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(94): Mage::run('test_b2c_asia', 'website')
#17 {main}
```

Comment: Which event you are using for `salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore` function? Also did you try changing `oa` to something else?

Comment: @John sales_order_grid_collection_load_before

Comment: did you try changing `oa` to something else?

Comment: yes, tried abc........

Comment: seems the method called twice, how can i avoid exportcsv avoid to run twice?